# loading qm file using QTranslator

Tags: qt, file, translation

I'm trying to use translation files. I went through all the procedures:
created ts file, translated it, but when I run the application, the language is still the same as before.

I worked on the Nokia example, just like in the instructions.

What could be my problem?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator* translator=new QTranslator(0);

    if(QFile::exists("hellotr_la.qm"))
        qWarning("failed-no file");

    if(! translator->load("hellotr_la.qm"))
        qWarning("failed loading"); //the warning appears ****

    app.installTranslator(translator);
}
```

Comment: Is that your exact code? That first "if" will only indicate failure if your file exists :) It should be if(! ...). So your file either doesn't exist in the executable directory or the name is incorrect.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Where are the .qm files located? Your code is attempting to load the file from the current working directory, which can be anything during runtime. Specify a directory path in the call to [`QTranslator::load`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html):

```
QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator();
if (translator->load("hellotr_la", "/path/to/folder/with/qm/files")) {
    app.installTranslator(translator);
}
```

Translations can be loaded from [Qt resources](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html), so it is a good idea to bundle them inside your executables. Then you would load them somewhat like this:

```
QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator();
if (translator->load("hellotr_la", ":/resources/translations")) {
    app.installTranslator(translator);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to translations in qt. I was stuck for an hour. Adding the qm file to my resources did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

The answer was already given in a comment, but I want to point it out clearly.

The first warning uses a wrong condition:

```
if(QFile::exists("hellotr_la.qm"))
    qWarning("failed-no file");
```

It should be:

```
if(!QFile::exists("hellotr_la.qm"))
    qWarning("failed-no file");
```

Since you only saw the second warning, but not the first one, the problem is indeed that the file was not found. Make sure that the working directory is what you expect it to be or (better) use the resource system as explained by andref.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example, can you simply try this :

```
 QTranslator translator;
 translator.load("hellotr_la");
 app.installTranslator(&translator);
```

Hope it will fix your problem !

Note 1 : No pointer here.
Note 2 : No extension in your filename.

Comment: Your "Note 1" is irrelevant. In fact it may be a source of problems if the QTranslator object is not created in the main() method.

Comment: "Note 2" is irrelevant too. QTranslator::load will do all kinds of magic to locate an appropriate translation file. That includes disconsidering the suffix (by default, ".qm") when searching the file.